# How to nest a square root in another square root?

Tags: math-mode, amsart

So I am trying to write using the `amsart` package

`($\sqrt[n]{X_{1}*...*X_{n}}$ *$\sqrt[n]{X_{n+1}*...*X_{2n}}$)^{1/2}` but instead of `^{1/2}` nested in another `sqrt`.

However

`$\sqrt[ ]{$\sqrt[n]{X_{1}*...*X_{n}}$ *$\sqrt[n]{X_{n+1}*...*X_{2n}}$}$`

doesn't show anything.
I just started using LaTeX today. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Sujiro You did it. Thanks very much. I see the key is to get rid of the interior $s. Any way I can give you reputation for this answer?

Comment: `*` might not be the proper multiplication sign. Consider `\cdot` or `\times`. Also, use special macros instead of `...` for better spacing, eg `*\dots*`, `\cdot\ldots\cdot` or `\times\dosts\times`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Don't use nested `$` in your equation. Try

```
$\sqrt[ ]{\sqrt[n]{X_{1}*...*X_{n}} *\sqrt[n]{X_{n+1}*...*X_{2n}}}$
```

Comment: Answer was correct and instantaneous couldn't wish for better.